# NPM Warnings "eslint X requires a peer of Y but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself."

Tags: node.js, npm, console, babeljs, eslint

Whenever I install a package I keep getting these npm warnings regarding eslint. I've tried every form of installing the latest version of eslint and babel-eslint that I can think of, but the same warning messages show every time. For instance if I run

> npm i babel-eslint

The follwing shows:

```html
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of babel-eslint@^7.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@1.9.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN firebase-functions@2.1.0 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Despite the warnings it shows that the package added. But if it's added then why do those warnings persist?

> - babel-eslint@10.0.1
>     removed 181 packages and updated 1 package in 50.436s

One thing I notice whenever I install via NPM is that at first the first line of the console shows

> [..................] - rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 1b360c8942244b42

Although it does go on to install the package, with those subsequent warning errors. Could anyone suggest a reason for all these errors and a possible way to fix them?